# GWT Developer Plugin - Does not seem to install or work correctly

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension

I know this has been asked many times but am I missing something? I can't seem to make it work...

I have followed the sample web app project here (http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html#creating) and when I go to run it as per the tutorial instructions (in Google Chrome) I get the message I need to install the plugin. I do that and it does not seem to work? I just go around in circles? It looks to me like the plugin is installed correctly?

Some advice is to 'drag n drop' the plugin to install it but that seems to be on Windows - I am on a MAC if that makes a difference...

Do I need to input any information in the 'options' section of the plugin? I have tried with 'localhost' and the ip that the web app produces but that does not seem to work?

I can get slightly further when using Firefox (although you need an older version for it to work - I installed 24.3 as it suggested). I get to a page that then says: "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:-1"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong…

Any advice?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is your GWT version ? Did you run with super dev mode ?

Comment: read about [super dev mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)

Comment: I am using GWT 2.6 as installed through the "Install New Software" option in Eclipse. I have looked at super dev mode and thought it was setup as in my xml file I have: <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out what I was doing wrong and I admit to my stupidity.

When you right click on your project in Eclpise and choose "Run As - Web Application" there is an option to use GWT (Super Dev Mode).

It was that simple I overlooked it!

It is strange that it does not say this in the tutorial I was working through. It just says to:

"Right-click on your web application project and select Debug As > Web Application"

Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found one more reason for this situation, except Super Dev Mode. If you run the project a couple of times the server 9997 will be busy with you'r previous project and finaly the connection failed. This is the reason for that -1 at the end of the port.

Solution:
1.You should use the red button(If you use Eclipse) to stop all projects
2.Run as-Web Application.